# Move existing app service into app service environment

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

We are currently running several Azure App Services which are having trouble with PCI-DSS compliance, due to the fact that App Services have TLSv1.0 enabled, with no option to disable it.  After reading around, it seems like App Service Environments [will allow us to do just that](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-custom-settings/#disable-tls-10).  However, I can't seem to figure out how to migrate our existing app to the new service environment.  Do we just have to create a new app from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

I assume your existing apps have already been deployed into existing App Service Plan? If so, you cannot move, all you can do is to [clone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview#clone-an-app-to-a-different-app-service-plan) it into a new ASP which has been deployed into your ASE

> Given the fact that an ASP’s location (within an ASE or in a shared public location) cannot be changed once it is created, you have to clone/duplicate the deployments when you scale your apps in this approach. It also implies that the order you create resources is ASE (optional), then ASP, and finally add App Service apps into an ASP.

Or you can see my ASP/ASE learning at my [blog](https://medium.com/@ericjwhuang/hosting-apis-in-azure-5bd5fa6f3375)

Comment: Cloning instructions are here now.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning#cloning-an-existing-app-to-an-app-service-environment