# Can QnA Maker Service use an existing app service plan within an ASE?

Tags: azure-qna-maker, azure-app-service-envrmnt

This is towards a planning effort for a web app deployment that uses QnA.
We would like to keep all our app service plans within our ASE ( Azure app service environment) boundary.

QnA Maker internally creates an app service plan. I would like to understand if it is possible for QnA maker service to create this app service plan inside our ASE.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how ASE really works, but if you can get the App Service to use an App Service Plan that is in your ASE, I should _think_ it would work. You might have come across these, but below are some links that might help.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/set-up-qnamaker-service-azure#share-existing-services-with-qna-maker https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709710/move-existing-app-service-into-app-service-environment https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning#cloning-an-existing-app-to-an-app-service-environment